# FacebookAPI with R. An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Tags: r

[image: Editor Screenshot]

```
# scrape the list of friends                                                                                                                          
friends <- facebook( path="me/friends" , token=acess_token)
# extract Facebook IDs                                                                                                                                
friends.id <- sapply(friends$data, function(x) x$id)
# extract names                                                                                                                                       
friends.name <- sapply(friends$data, function(x)  iconv(x$name,"UTF-8","ASCII//TRANSLIT"))
# short names to initials                                                                                                                             
initials <- function(x) paste(substr(x,1,1), collapse="")
friends.initial <- sapply(strsplit(friends.name," "), initials)
```

I have error:

```
friends.initial <- sapply(strsplit(friends.name," "), initials)

Error in strsplit(friends.name, " ") : non-character argument
```

Comment: This error message is not related to Rfacebook, but to the fact that your object friends.name is not a 'character' type.

Comment: how i can fix that

Comment: Change the name of your post, plus, post here the result of str(friends.name)

Comment: i can't get information of friends. Have error: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user

Comment: That's because you need a token.  Have you tried to get one?  Maybe your real issue is in that code.